# Conflict between AnythingSlider and MP4 Video Player with Splash Image

Tags: conflict, flowplayer, anythingslider

I have the following issue.

NOTE: I AM NOT A CODER!
(I can follow instructions & I know some HTML and know my around basic stuff on Wordpress sites; but that's it.)

On my test site at http://www.auctionsolutionsnow.com, if you see the SLIDER & the FIRST VIDEO:

There is an ISSUE between EasyVideoPlayer (www.easyvideoplayer.com), my video player (which has FLOWPLAYER under the hood),
and the slider, AnythingSlider => www.css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#panel1-6

Any idea how to debug this?

The SPLASH IMAGE of the first video in slide 1 is the problem!
(This is not supposed to auto-play either...)

Not sure if this is necessarily a JAVASCRIPT issue.

The problem is some kind of conflict with EasyVideoPlayer (EVP), when used in conjunction with that slider.
From EVP support: because of how splash images modify the functionality a little, they do tend to conflict.

WITHOUT using a splash image, you can see it working fine on www.jazzheaven.com, for example.

BTW, videos are hosted on Amazon S3 and are using Cloudfront/RTMP Streaming.

Any suggestions, I would highly appreciate it!

Again: I can follow specific instructions, but i am NOT a super-techie or coder!
(I do know some HTML, but no javascript, no CSS, etc.)

Thank you in advance!

Falk

PS: (This probably belongs in a separate thread...:)

When I see my website www.jazzheaven.com from my iPhone: the 2 DROP-DOWNS (called 'Choose Your Instrument' and 'Click here to Choose Your Instrument' do NOT work. ;(

My WP developer said this is a 2-min job for somebody who understands JQUERY.

2ND QUESTION: would fixing this solve it for IPHONES and ANDROIDS and iPADS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to figure out why there is a difference between having and not having the splash image. But because the player is being added using a `<script>` tag, try initializing anythingSlider when the window is loaded instead of document ready (window load activates when all images and videos have loaded):

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
 jQuery('#slider-home-videos').anythingSlider({ 
  delay: 6000, 
  height: 390, 
  startStopped: true, 
  buildArrows: true, 
  hashTags: false, 
  navigationFormatter: function(index, slide) { 
   return ['Ralph Peterson', 'Ari 800px test to fit', 'slide 3'][index - 1]; 
  } 
 }); 
});
```

As for your questions about the dropdown, please post that in a separate question... I don't own an "and" or "i"-anything so I can't help you there =(

Comment: Thank you, fudgey!

I now used your code, and it DOES show the splash image correctly.
BUT..., the slider is GONE, and the 2nd video just shows up below...

See http://auctionsolutionsnow.com/test-re-slider-and-evp-splash-image-conflict/

Comment: Opps sorry, the `$` I had in there wasn't defined, I switched it to `jQuery` in the code above... it should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't work. But maybe I put your code in there in the wrong way? See here: http://auctionsolutionsnow.com/test-re-slider-and-evp-splash-image-conflict/

Comment: Some more intel I got from somebody else: The dang thing is being set to autoplay for some reason when you say you disabled autoplay in the EasyVideoPlayer generator.

You wont be able to fix it right away as its a problem from the host.

See here: http://screencast.com/t/tuuTv0VPXF

This is not the source code view...
This won't show up in source code view...

Look at the autoplay setting marked by the arrow... it gets sets to true when the video is in the slider...

Comment: I think the best solution then would be to copy the code you can see in that image (use Firebug in Firefox, it makes it really easy to copy the HTML) then paste that into the slider instead of the script tag. Then change the autoplay option to false.